# led-strip showing wrong color

Tags: python, led

i got a problem with my led-strip. It shows always a different color. Like when i want to show purple picture it shows blue instead. I'm not a big expert in python, so i can't figure it out :/

Here's the code. It's all working except showing the right colors. Maybe there's something wrong configured?

```
import time
from neopixel import *
from PIL import Image
import sys

# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT   = 50      # Number of LED pix.
LED_PIN     = 18      # GPIO pin connected to the pix (must support PWM!).
LED_FREQ_HZ = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA     = 5       # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 5)
LED_INVERT  = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor 
level shift)

# method to blank all LEDs
def blankLine():
    for x in range(LED_COUNT):
    strip.setPixelColorRGB(x, 0,0,0)
    strip.show()

# method to resize picture and show in column per column on the led strip
def showPicture(filename, strip):
    blankLine()
    # open file
    img = Image.open(filename).convert("RGB")

    # resize file
    newWidth = float(img.size[0])/float(img.size[1])*LED_COUNT
    img = img.resize( (int(newWidth), LED_COUNT))

    width = img.size[0]
    height = img.size[1]

    pix = img.load()

    for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
    strip.setPixelColorRGB(y, pix[x,y][0], pix[x,y][1], pix[x,y][2])
    strip.show()
    time.sleep(0.3)

    blankLine()

# Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, 
LED_INVERT)

# Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
strip.begin()
showPicture(sys.argv[1], strip)
```

Comment: Could the LED strip be wired not-as-expected?

Comment: It is wired correctly. I just used another script and it showed the correct colors just fine. The problem exists only with this script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
I had the same issue with my 2812b LEDs as they seem not to be RGB but rather GRB.
you have to add one more param when you create the strip object:

```
strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA,LED_INVERT, ws.WS2811_STRIP_GRB)
```